# Could a ticket from London to Cape Town cost the same in 2016 as it did in 1976?

Tags: air-travel, factoids, fares, history

I have paid £760 for next weeks ticket from Heathrow to Cape Town via Jo'burg with SAA. I believe this to be the same as I paid in January 1976. I appreciate the variables such as when booked etc. but is my memory playing tricks or can some one confirm £760 was approximately correct?

Comment: Just because I was curious... Using the Bank of England's [inflation calculator](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/education/Pages/resources/inflationtools/calculator/flash/default.aspx) that £760 in 1976 would cost ~£4886 in 2014 (the most recent year the calculator will allow you to enter).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the history of airfare pricing

Comment: The inflation calculator would not be pertinent in this case. The ticket now _should_ cost ~5000 today, and in terms of actual value of the pound probably _does_ cost that much in terms of purchasing power, etc, but the face value on the ticket today is the same as 40 years ago.

Comment: Also it's well documented that ticket prices have dropped over time - prices often haven't moved in a long, long time. (eg http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2013/02/how-airline-ticket-prices-fell-50-in-30-years-and-why-nobody-noticed/273506/)

Comment: Inflation is kind of relevant, it explains why the face value on the ticket could still be the same even if air transport became vastly cheaper.

Answer (score 6):

In 1960, a round-trip from New York to London cost $350, according to a [Pan Am advertisement](https://cdn0.rubylane.com/shops/sharp-objects/110916-2.1L.jpg). The same trip today, booked out-of-season, in economy class, with a layover and sufficiently in advance costs around $550, an increase of **60%**. The [official inflation rate](http://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/cpicalc.pl?cost1=1000&year1=1976&year2=2016) was around **800%** over the same time period, so it seems that the *cheapest* air fares have decreased by around **80%**. Various sources confirm that air-travel prices have [indeed gone down](http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2013/02/how-airline-ticket-prices-fell-50-in-30-years-and-why-nobody-noticed/273506/):

[image: air travel prices chart]

Therefore the answer is **yes**, it's feasible that the dollar value of both tickets stayed the same over the years.

Comment: I'm being a bit blind here. Where did the OP say they bought J?

Comment: No way! Modern business class has a flat bed. You didn't even get that in F in the 70s. Screw the food!

Comment: @Berwyn I was making a comparison with 1960, since I couldn't find exact fares in 1976. In 1960 the seats were definitely much better than modern economy, as well as everything else in the airports.

Comment: They might've been better than modern economy, but they certainly were nothing like modern business.

Comment: @Berwyn Let's continue in chat.

Comment: Subtraction is not the correct algorithm; prices can not go down more than 100%. In 1960 dollars the current fare is 20% of the 1960 fare, so prices went down 80%.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'm an idiot. Fixed.

Comment: What about flight entertainment? Vastly improved aircrafts (noise, cabin pressure)? And even taking your argument that economy class was more comfortable in the 1960s at face value and ignoring @Berwyn excellent points, it's still absurd to compare the cheapest fare with business class fares. Minute differences in food aside, the main service you are getting is crossing the Atlantic in a matter of hours and that has become much cheaper. So I think you are the one making an apple to orange comparison and ruining an otherwise excellent answer with this silly and unnecessary comparison.

Comment: @Relaxed answer updated